# Error while taking pictures using MeteorCamera.getPicture() while testing on a laptop

Tags: meteor, meteor-plugin

I am working to add a photo ability to my app using Meteor's mdg:camera plugin.  For now, I don't have any PhoneGap devices setup, so I am testing on my laptop.  I thought I read somewhere that the Meteor implementation would fall-back and use a simple file dialog when a camera wasn't available, but when I try to run the following code on my laptop:

```
var cameraOptions = {
    width: 800,
    height: 600
};

MeteorCamera.getPicture(cameraOptions, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        // TODO Need to handle the error
    } else {
        if (!this.photos) {
            this.photos = [];
        }

        this.photos.push({ submitted_by: Meteor.userId(), submitted_on: new Date(), photo_data: data});
    }
});
```

I get the error:

```
Meteor.makeErrorType.errorClass {error: "unknownError", reason: "There was an error while accessing the camera.", details: undefined, message: "There was an error while accessing the camera. [unknownError]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"…}
```

I would actually like for users to be able to upload photos via the same button when using a laptop.  For what it's worth, I actually do have a camera built-in, and I am developing on a 15" MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On browser client, the `mdg:camera` falls back on using `navigator.getUserMedia` to try to obtain a video stream from the webcam, it does not allow the user to upload a photo.

https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/blob/master/packages/mdg:camera/photo-browser.js#L41

Unfortunately as we are speaking `getUserMedia` lacks support on Safari, which is probably the browser you are using working on a MacBook.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream

Try your application on Google Chrome or Firefox instead.

Comment: I am actually using Chrome.  Safari is the devil.  Any tips for getting it working?  I know my webcam light is off, so perhaps it's because I somehow have it disabled?

Comment: On the right-most part of the address bar in chrome, you should see a video camera icon, if it's disabled it will be crossed out red, click on it to change permissions, if everything is working you should be prompted for user permission to access the webcam when the call to `getUserMedia` is performed.

Comment: If `mdg:camera` falls back to `navigator.getUserMedia` what is the general way to cause a mobile web browser to access camera and/or the photo library if my app is being used in mobile web (e.g. Safari)?  I just tried Facebook in mobile Safari and it shows buttons that allow both a camera photo and photo library - it's slick! On the desktop I could use device detection to show a different interface.  I guess I could use the `Meteor.isCordova` to also switch out the interface for mobile Safari?