# How to use Meteor-PhoneGap Plugin

Tags: cordova, meteor, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am getting started with using the PhoneGap integration with Meteor and is having trouble getting the plugin to work. Could someone please provide steps below how I would use the camera plugin. Currently I am only running it on the simulator. Code is below. Thank in advance.

I added the camera plugin like this:
    meteor add cordova:org.apache.cordova.camera@0.3.1

Then to use it I have the following code:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.hello.events({
    'click button': function () {
      // increment the counter when button is clicked
      navigator.camera.getPicture(
        function(data){ Session.set("picture", res); },

        function(err){ console.log(err); },

        {
          quality: 50,
          destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
        }
      );
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

When I click on the button I get this error:

```
I20141006-21:58:33.174(-7)? (ios) Camera.getPicture: source type 1 not available.
I20141006-21:58:33.222(-7)? (ios) no camera available
```

Comment: I do not believe the iPhone simulator allows GPS or photos.  Chrome will allow you to do both, I found.

Comment: @CodeChimp this code launches the camera on the Android emulator, but does not work on the browser. Any thoughts?

Comment: See my question from a few weeks ago:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26182267/error-while-taking-pictures-using-meteorcamera-getpicture-while-testing-on-a-l

Answer (score 0):

According Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap integration docs,

> Any functionality which relies on a Cordova/Phonegap plugin should
>   wrap code in a Meteor.startup() block

Docs [link here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration#adding-cordovaphonegap-specific-javascript-code-to-your-application)